# Why is my Spring MVC application showing HTML source code in WAS9 production environment?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

JSP pages sometimes showing html viewsource code rather than showing output.

This application is running in production for last two years and suddenly all the jsp pages showing html viewsource code when accessing menu(sometimes only). I didnt change any code. Its running in WAS9 server and only in production environment it showing this beahaviour. The same code is in QA and there is no problem in QA. Im using spring mvc. Is there any problem with server environment or my times?